# Fetch Products from database with category and subcategory attached

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am building a web api and want to fetch all the products from product table I have in my database and I also want to include the category and subcategory which are in two other tables. How do I do then? So one product should display this
Category = Electronics Subcategory = TV and product = LG TV 40

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Entity Framework Core** and you want to load a foreign key navigational property, then load another navigational property that is inside it:

```
var products = db.Products
.Include(x => x.Category) 
.ThenInclude(x => x.Subcategory)
.ToList(); 

// Use .Include() to load a navigational property
// Use .ThenInclude() to load a navigational property's navigational property
```

Comment: Im not using Entity Framework core